# How to dissolve grass/leaves without affecting enclosure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I've got two questions:

1. What sort of compound can dissolve grass/leaves fastest without leaving "much" trace?
2. What sort of enclosure is required for this to be doen safely and without damaging the enclosure?

I am doing a small experiment and would like to try dissolving few leaves within a glass or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plant matter is mostly cellulose which is insoluble in most solvents so it is unlikely you can "dissolve" the material.  You can react the material.  Two possibilities are nitric acid and sulfuric acid but there are a number of safety precautions you need to follow.

Comment: Ok, thank You very much. Is there something that is safer but yields similar results?